# Find if an item comes before another item in an array

Tags: ruby

I want to find out if one item in an array comes after another item in an array (or reversed: if it comes before the other item).

Say, I have the array `[:new, :draft, :published]`, and a `current_state` as well as `this_state`, in a class. A method now allows me to check of the current `State` is finished; if it lies behind the `current_state` in the list of states:

```
class State
  def initialize(this_state, current_state, all_states)
    @this_state = this_state
    @current_state = current_state
    @all_states = all_states
  end

  def done?
    @all_states.index(@this_state) < @all_states.index(@current_state)
  end
end
```

I can now use that as follows:

```
assert(State.new(:new, :draft, [:new, :draft, :published]).done?)
refute(State.new(:draft, :draft, [:new, :draft, :published]).done?)
refute(State.new(:published, :draft, [:new, :draft, :published]).done?)
```

I'm not particularly interested in the use-case where the array contains an item multiple times (e.g. `[:new, :draft, :published, :draft]`), as that is covered by the code generating the array already (it will be uniq).

Is there a more expressive way, or an actual API for this, in ruby, or is comparing indexes the best way?

Comment: Other than the fact that I am uncertain of the applicability of this code (e.g. why you need to inject all the 2 states and the list of all states) I can see no objection to using the ordered list and indices to determine the workflow

Comment: If `done?` will be executed repeatedly consider making `all_states` a hash: `all_states = ['a', 'b', 'c']; @all_states = all_states.each_with_index.to_h #=> { 'a'=>0, 'b'=>1, 'c'=>2 }`.

Comment: @engineersmnky I'm in doubt of this design as well. But I fail to see any pattern that would allow me to have `State` know wether it has been `done?`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I fail to see the benefit of your suggestion: Hashes are unordered, and so we'll need to simulate ordering with the values. Which then breaks any potential micro-optimisation. Or am I missing a benefit?

Comment: It would allow you to write the operative line of `done?` as `@all_states.index[@this_state] < @all_states[@current_state]`, but perhaps I've misunderstood your question. In any event, it has nothing to do with the order of the hash's keys.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think using `index` as you suggested in your question is the most expressive way to write it. But a more efficient solution is below, which is a trivial performance improvement for short `all_states` arrays, but if `all_states` gets long or if this is called a lot, maybe go for this solution ‍♂️

```rb
class State
  def initialize(this_state, current_state, all_states)
    @this_state = this_state
    @current_state = current_state
    @all_states = all_states
  end

  def done?
    @this_state == @all_states.detect{ |state| state == @this_state || state == @current_state }
  end
end
```